# C Shell (csh) Backspace key cancels the command not erasing the command

Tags: shell, csh

In my **HP-UX** (B.11.23 U ia64) box, **Csh** is running as login shell.

```
what /usr/bin/csh
```

*sh.lex.c $Date: 2005/02/28 10:00:30 $Revision: r11.23/2 PATCH_11.23 (PHCO_32667)
         $Revision: @(#) csh R11.23_BL2005_0301_1 PATCH_11.23 PHCO_32667*

But when I type any command in the prompt and press **Backspace** key then the typed command gets cancelled and the cursor goes to the next line without executing the command. The erasing of the command is not happening.
I have tried setting:

```
stty erase <backspace>

stty erase ^H
```

but did not work.

I would like to know how to make the **Backspace** key work as normal, that is, it has to erase the typed characters

```
stty -a

*speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
rows = 24; columns = 80
min = 1; time = 1;
intr = DEL; quit = ^\; erase = DEL; kill = @
eof = ^D; eol = ^@; eol2 <undef>; swtch <undef>
stop = ^S; start = ^Q; susp <undef>; dsusp <undef>
werase <undef>; lnext <undef>
-parenb -parodd cs8 -cstopb hupcl cread -clocal -loblk -crts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iuclc
ixon ixany -ixoff -imaxbel -rtsxoff -ctsxon -ienqak
isig icanon -iexten -xcase echo -echoe echok -echonl -noflsh
-echoctl -echoprt -echoke -flusho -pendin
opost -olcuc onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel -tostop tab3*
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your terminal is sending some other character than `^H` (<kbd>control+H</kbd>), for example `DEL` (commonly echoed as `^?`).  You might see that character in the output of `stty -a`.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually fixed with typing:

> stty erase <kbd>Control + V</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>

To get the current settings, run:

```
stty -a
```

Edit:

The issue is DEL is set to both the erase and interrupt characters, fix the latter with:

> stty intr <kbd>Control + C</kbd>

Alternatively:

```
stty intr `printf "\03"`
```

Comment: Thanks jlliagre. It worked now. Though it does not erase the character when pressing Backspace but it run-over on it and make me to type again and correct it.